# Creating, assign user rigths and loading dump into mysql from a perl bash gives mysql error "no database selected"

Tags: mysql, sql, linux, bash

I have a bash that creates a database, assign user rigths to it and then load a dump. I do this from a bash in opensuse. A parameter with database name is used = $1.

This is the part of my script that handles this:

```
echo "creating database"
#(This is Line 22)create new database and configure grants
mysql -hlocalhost -uroot -e "create database $1;"

echo "select db, use"
mysql -hlocalhost -uroot -e "use $1;"

echo "granting rights"
mysql -hlocalhost -uroot -e "grant all on $1.* to 'smic_db_root'@'localhost' identified by 
'sm_for_all_987';"

echo "loading dump"
#load the database dump
mysql -h localhost -uroot $1</opt/otrsadm/otrs_template.sql
```

And this is from my error log:

```
 creating database
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
select db, use
ERROR at line 1: USE must be followed by a database name
granting rights
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* to 'smic_db_root'@'localhost' identified by 
'sm_for_all_987'' at line 1
loading dump
ERROR 1046 (3D000) at line 22: No database selected
```

How do I do in order to chose the database in the bash and when do I need to do it. Since the error message is refering to Line 22, I need to do it somewhere inside. I tried adding the use $1; like this:

```
mysql -hlocalhost -uroot -e "create database $1; **use $1;** grant all on $1.* to 'smic_db_root'@'localhost' identified by 'sm_for_all_987';"
```

No difference in behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create/grant commands don't need a database to be selected. They explicitly work at the global level (create) or on the mysql database (grant). Try putting in some debugging to see eactly where the error(s) occuring?

```
echo "creating database"
mysql .... 'create database ..';
echo "granting rights"
mysql .... 'grant ....';
echo "loading dump"
mysql .... < file.sql
```

Right now the error messages do not tell you WHAT failed, just that something did. With the echoes added as above, you'll at least know which stage caused which error(s).

Comment: Ok, I updated my bash and my post with the result. It still seem to be about chosing the database.

Comment: It would appear that $1 isn't set properly. Try creating the query string into a var (`query="..... $1...."`) and echoing that out, to see what the full query line looks like before it goes into MySQL. The "use must be followed by a databasename" error is indicative that your query is `create ; use ; grant all on .* to .....` and not `create xyz; use xyz; grant all on xyz.* etc...`

Comment: Thanks! Yes, the problem was that the paramters was not posted to the bash properly. Fixed now!